# arguments.callee in Racket (Scheme)?

Tags: javascript, arguments, scheme, racket

I need the feature `arguments.callee` of JavaScript in Racket (Scheme). Do you know how?

Here, an example in JavaScript

```js
function makeFactorialFunc() {
 return function(x) {
   if (x <= 1)
     return 1;
   return x * arguments.callee(x - 1);
 };
}
```

Comment: Note that `arguments.callee` is not available in JavaScript strict mode. For the same reason that feature is not available in Scheme/Racket. (It makes efficient compilation difficult) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think `arguments.callee` is useful when you need to dynamically wrap a script with functions and call this new function in a recursive way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot get the currently executing function in a dynamic way in Racket, but you can certainly still implement the function in your question in Racket, just by giving the function a name:

```
(define (make-factorial-func)
  (define (func x)
    (if (<= x 1)
        1
        (* x (func (- x 1)))))
  func)
```

It’s possible that you feel like you need the dynamic-ness of `arguments.callee` for some reason, and it might be possible to achieve that goal through some other mechanism, but seeing as you don’t provide any context for *why* you think it’s necessary in your question, I can’t guess as to what that other mechanism might be.

Comment: One could also use [SRFI-31 `rec`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-31/srfi-31.html)